# "that' in a clause

Tags: grammaticality

In a formal scientific writing, is it better to keep that in a clause where you can omit it?

E.g.

In an objective clause: This implies (that) the sun is the center of the universe.

In a relative clause: The group (that) we took special actions are not influenced.

Comment: Look at it this way: every optional marker you delete removes a flag that the reader can use to parse your sentence. Markers like _that_ are not data, since they only have structural information; but deleting structural information is an avoidable source of ambiguity, when clarity matters. On the other hand, leaving all the markers in clutters the path the reader must take. A good rule is to vary constructions and not always be using the same kind of clauses, which produces fewer _that_'s.

Comment: This is *possibly* a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/455779/he-discovered-that-his-father-had-a-special-box-in-the-basement/455783#455783, but it's not clear as you may be asking for advice about *that* in a specifically scientific context. I'm not sure if that makes a difference, but perhaps it might.

Comment: To the extent that you're asking about an **accepted style in scientific writing**, rather than about the actual grammatical usage, your question might be more appropriate to our sibling site [Writing.SE]. If you don't get a satisfactory answer here at EL&U, flag your question and ask for it to be migrated. :-)